# How to load GhostScript (gs64dll.dll) 64 bit dll in ASP.net 2010 application (It gives error with error code: HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Tags: c#

To do this I have created c# wrapper and put gs64dll.dll in bin folder still it gives the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using the 32-bit DLL instead, out of interest? Perhaps it's running in a 32-bit process.

Answer (score 1):

Googling the HRESULT show that this is most likely a 64bit vs 32bit issue.  Try using `gs32dll.dll` or the 32-bit version instead.

The other option is to change your application pool for the website to use 64bit.  (I believe 32-bit is default).

Comment: I tried it but gives the same error. The dll (gs64dll.dll) works properly for window application but it not working with web.

Comment: Can you check the Windows Event logs?  I have a feeling you'll see a error message like: `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem. What I ended up doing is using `gs32dll.dll` and selecting in Config. Manager platform x86.  That solved it.